# Where should optipng be installed in OSX for HTML5 Boilerplate

Tags: unix, html5boilerplate

I have installed optipng in user/bin directory.  cd to user/bin and running optipng -? shows opting is installed.

Running ant minify, brings up this error:

```
[echo] You have optipng installed and your version is: 
 [echo] *** optipng NOT INSTALLED. SKIPPING OPTIMIZATION OF PNGs.
 [echo] *** Install optipng to enable png optimization.
```

Does this mean HTML5Boilerplate expects optipng installed in a different directory, and if so, which one?

Answer (score 1):

OptiPng just needs to be in your path. If it's in your path you should be fine. If you can run optipng from the command line outside of its install directory it's in your path.

The actual problem is with the version check. It's kind of a hack so it's not exactly robust. I wanted to try to automate the version check and it turns out it's entirely bulletproof. Bummer. I'm going to move it to a manual flag and a page in the wiki (basically one feature in the build script relies on optipng 7+ and it will crap out in < 7, hence the version test. People will just have to flag it themselves.)